# How can I change the color of texts when they are moved to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I hope to make a draggable element more interactive by changing its color when it is in the drop field. But I haven't figured how to do that with the current code.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!-- Begin draggable area -->
            <div class="draggable">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h2 class="window-title">Spectra</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="draggable-spectra">   <!--draggable element-->
                      <h3>Menu</h3>
                      <p class= "element">dasdsa</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="draggable-spectra"><h3>Content</h3></div>  <!--draggable element-->
                </div>
             </div>
<!-- End draggable -->

            <!-- Begin Drop Area -->
            <div class="droppable-spectra">
                <h2 id="drop">Drop-box</h2>
            </div>
            <!-- end Drop Area -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/drag.js"></script>  <!--js file where I have the code below-->
```

Here is my code for JS (thanks to aSeptik):

```
$(function() {
$(".draggable-spectra").draggable({
    revert : function(event, ui) {
        // on older version of jQuery use "draggable"
        // $(this).data("draggable")
        // on 2.x versions of jQuery use "ui-draggable"
        // $(this).data("ui-draggable")
        $(this).data("uiDraggable").originalPosition = {
            top : 0,
            left : 0
        };

        // if (event === false){
        //   $(".element").data("color","blue")
        // };
        // return boolean
        return !event;
        // that evaluate like this:
        // return event !== false ? false : true;
    }
});
$(".droppable-spectra").droppable();});
```

Now it works like this (it is an example from aSeptik):
http://so.devilmaycode.it/revert-a-jquery-draggable-object-back-to-its-original-container-on-out-event-of-d/

But how could I change the text color in the draggable box when it is placed in the droppable box? I have tried .data() but it did not work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You probably need to implement a callback when you are done dragging, isn't it documented?

Comment: You have your `if` block __after__ the `return`, so it will never be reached. But why do you think `.data("color", "blue")` will change the text color?

Comment: Could you add enough code that we can actually reproduce your problem? The comment of `<!-- begin drop area -->` is of no use to us at all. Provide a *complete* [MCVE] please.

Comment: @ David Thomas, I am so sorry. I am new to JS and also new to this website. I think now the code is enough to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#element').droppable({
    drop: callback,
    greedy: true
});
```

I think you need to implement something like this.

http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `drop` event callback of droppable widget as shown below:

```js
$(".draggable-spectra").draggable();
$(".droppable-spectra").droppable({
  drop: function(e, ui) {
    ui.draggable.css('color', 'blue');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!-- Begin draggable area -->
<div class="draggable">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h2 class="window-title">Spectra</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="draggable-spectra">
      <!--draggable element-->
      <h3>Menu</h3>
      <p class="element">dasdsa</p>
    </div>
    <div class="draggable-spectra">
      <h3>Content</h3>
    </div>
    <!--draggable element-->
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End draggable -->

<!-- Begin Drop Area -->
<div class="droppable-spectra">
  <h2 id="drop">Drop-box</h2>
</div>
<!-- end Drop Area -->
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am new to this, and I know it might be way advanced for me to do this right now. But if I just wanna change the color of element with the class "element", what should I do? I tried to do "$(".element").ui.draggable.css('color', 'blue')", but it won't work.                   Also, any hint on how to get the color back when it is reverted?

Comment: @KabeLee You should do `ui.draggable.find('.element').css('color', 'blue');`. For getting the color back you can use the [stop](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop) callback

Comment: @T J, you saved my day! The problem I used "stop" is that when I added this code "stop: function(event,ui){
        ui.draggable.find('.element').css('color','black');
      }" inside droppable(), then the element cannot be dragged. I guess I must put it in the wrong place? or I should return a value?

Comment: @KabeLee stop is an event of draggable, not droppable

Comment: @T J, I am sorry. I made an typo. I did use stop in draggable, but after I did that, the element cannot be moved. The code is as below: `$(".draggable-spectra").draggable({
        revert : function(event, ui) {
            $(this).data("uiDraggable").originalPosition = {
                top : 0,
                left : 0
            };
            return !event;
        }
        stop: function( event, ui ) {
          ui.draggable.find('.element').css('color','black');
        }
    });`